# Android Studio 3.1.3 not found Volley Library

Tags: android, android-volley

Today I have updated my Android Studio from 2.2 to 3.1.3.

At the beginning everything seems to works fine. I fixed some errors and successfully build my project. But when I tried to edit a class that is using [Android Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) I figured out Android Studio is not finding any symbol from Volley library, as is shown in the next image:

[image: Android Studio cannot find symbols from Volley Library]

Before update Android Studio it was working fine. Even now my project compiles successfully, install the apk in a physical device, and volley is working properly executing http request and even getting a picture from a facebook profile, I can call mi backend API and I receive a correct response. It seem like if just Android Studio didn't has any knowledge about existence of Volley Library.

This is mi build.gradle where I include Volley (I have replaced all **compiles** for **implementation**):

[image]

Thank You in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Try `volley:1.1.1` and add `google()` repository

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes!!! That fix the problem! Thank you so much. Maybe post your comment as answer to mark as correct answer. Anyway thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll want to make sure that you have `google()` listed before `jcenter()` or some other `maven` repo in the `repositories` section of the Gradle files

Then, Volley 1.1.1 was just released, so try that version instead.